# WordPress добавление нового атрибута в WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добавляю новый атрибут в Woocommerce

```
$attribute = array(
                'attribute_label'   => $attr,
                'attribute_name'    => $attr_filt,
                'attribute_type'    => 'select',
                'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'attribute_public'  => 0
            );
            global $wpdb; 
        $insert = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies', $attribute );

        if ( is_wp_error( $insert ) ) {
            throw new WC_API_Exception( 'woocommerce_api_cannot_create_product_attribute', $insert->get_error_message(), 400 );
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added', $wpdb->insert_id, $attribute );
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );
```

Добавление происходит успешно, в списке атрибутов магазина появляются нужные значения, но если я сразу за этим кодом пытаюсь присвоить этому атрибуту значение, то у меня выпадает ошибка "Неверная таксономия".

```
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $attr_param, 'pa_'.$sh, true );
```

Если я запускаю скрипт ещё раз (атрибут уже создан предыдущим запуском и создание отсеивается по условию), то никакой ошибки таксономии не выпадает.

Как с этим бороться?